# Does Maven support incremental builds?

Tags: java, maven

How does one use Maven to support incremental builds? Is there a guide somewhere? (top Google results are disappointing)

Comment: Give it a try with Bing - "Incremental Maven Build" - it gave me this which is quite good - [blog on incremental build plugin](http://harshana05.blogspot.com/2011/05/apache-maven-incremental-build-support.html)

Comment: But it doesn't provide functionality of "Incremental Testing", all modules' tests will be run eventhough build happens incrementally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven builds incrementally by default, but it turns out that the compiler plugin (i.e., the core of javac) is so fast that building fresh every time is not a bottleneck with sane codebase sizes, not by comparison with constructing large assemblies or running large test suites. (Java, like most languages, is much faster to compile than C++.)

Comment: For comparison, in my code the time spent compiling Java code is about 1% of the total time to build, maybe less. It's short enough that I _simply don't care_ to try to optimize it further.

Comment: The problem is exactly in all other build steps (primarily unit testing, packaging, other plugins like assembly, etc.) which depend on compilation phase. If they got triggered regardless of whether there were any changes to compile or not, you've got all the time wasted people try to avoid when they ask for incremental builds.

Comment: Maven does not build incrementally. The creator of Maven is working on this with a new lifecycle. I have absolutely no idea why the moderator @Ryan deleted an answered that referenced this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28224819/revisions

Comment: `the compiler plugin is so fast that building fresh every time is not a bottleneck with sane codebase sizes` - Seriously? That reasoning is the same as: Why would you fix a bug that keeps crashing your application which automatically restarts super fast while fixing the bug would take hours.

Comment: The likes of this answer, is exactly the reason I'll never willingly use maven. Poor documentation. No straight answers. Far too much "Woo" hocus pocus.

Comment: Yes, compilation is fast. But unnecessary compilation still slows down a build, because changed timestamps of classes/jars make it impossible/hard to reliably avoid unnecessary rerunning of tests etc. The whole build system needs to be designed with incremental object graphs in mind. Unfortunately maven hasn't been.

Comment: Using tools like gradle, it's not just about avoiding the running of javac, it's also about avoiding tasks that depend on the output of javac.  That is, gradle can also avoid running test tasks if the sources for that module haven't changed.  Maven fails because it has to run all tasks every time, as it has no notion of "if you didn't change the jar from projectA, don't build or test projectB".

Comment: IDK, my simple Java API server takes at least 5 seconds to build/run using `mvn -offline -T 16 package exec:java -DskipTests` and I am on a very fast machine.

Comment: This answer is not correct as compiling is just a small part of building.

Answer (score 23):

I can't quite figure out the dynamic that drives the Maven community but it isn't one that's friendly to having fine-grained control over your build-process.

Anyhow, after digging around I found an answer that worked for me here: http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Java-Maven-Compile-Only-Changed-Files

Note that setting the value to `false` confused me at first, but an explanation is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653164/409638

Reproduced here for convenience:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It's the `useIncrementalCompilation` set to `false` that is key here.

I can confirm that when I run my build I have gone from:

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 114 source files to /home/vagrant/workspace/splat/target/classes
```

to

```
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/vagrant/workspace/splat/target/classes
```

which has shaved a few seconds of my incremental build. Now all I've got to do is figure out how to disable all the other unnecessary cruft that's slowing down my edit/evaluate cycles ...

Comment: To disable all the other unnecessary cruft, try look this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11081252/1767021

Comment: I decided to treat my build issues as an X/Y problem, and just eliminated Maven. Everybody is much happier now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [maven-incremental build plugin](http://maven-incremental-build.java.net/site/usage.html), if your project has hundreds of modules. It saves lot of time.

Comment: I am assuming this is similar to maven 3.1 incremental compilation
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: It's been moved to GitHub: https://github.com/vsellier/maven-incremental-build

Answer (score 6):

Update: truly incremental build support - similar to one in Gradle - has made it in Maven code base. Introduction video is here: https://youtu.be/DEQG4CNFMFE

Update2: maven build cache extension officially released - https://github.com/apache/maven-build-cache-extension

Kind regards
Alex

Comment: Just a hint what to expect - build time for 700+ modules project reduces from 50 mins to 4 mins

Answer (score 5):

## Takari Maven Lifecycle

Yes, it is possible now thanks to [takari-lifecycle-plugin](https://github.com/takari/takari-lifecycle). Take look at this sample project: [maven-incremental-compilation](https://github.com/mariuszs/maven-incremental-compilation)

### Sample output

```
[INFO] --- takari-lifecycle-plugin:1.10.2:compile (default-compile) @ maven-incremental-compilation ---
[INFO] Performing incremental build
[INFO] Compiling 2 sources to /home/mariuszs/maven-incremental-compilation/target/classes
[INFO] Compiled 1 out of 2 sources (670 ms)
```

### More information

- [TEAM Documentation - The Takari Lifecycle](http://takari.io/book/40-lifecycle.html)
- [Java Incremental Compilation](http://takari.io/2014/10/16/incremental-compilation.html)

Answer (score 4):

Maven supports building subsets of multi module projects using the command line arguments `-pl`, `-am` and `-amd` to specify modules to build, also build dependencies and also build dependents, respectively. It will also only compile changed source files in any given module (not really a Maven feature so much as a javac feature).