# Compiling only selected files in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to compile only selected files or directories (including subdirectories) within source directory. I was pretty sure I can do this using `<includes>` of `maven-compiler-plugin`'s configuration, but it seems to not work as I expect since it still compiles all classes into `target/classes`. What is really strange, Maven output suggest that the setting actually does its work, because with:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>com/example/dao/bean/*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I have:

```
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to c:\Projects\test\target\classes
```

but with no compiler's configuration I have:

```
[INFO] Compiling 14 source file to c:\Projects\test\target\classes
```

In both cases however, all 14 classes are compiled into `target/classes` as I mentioned. Can you explain that or suggest another solution to compile only selected files?

Comment: Did you remember to do a clean before testing it?

Comment: Have you tried excluding **/* before? I guess that by default maven includes everything and you have to exclude. Are you using an IDE with an "autobuild" option set by a chance (such as Eclipse)?

Comment: Yes, I clean before compile. Yes, I tried to exlude `**/*.java`. I don't use IDE this time. Just plain `pom.xml` and console.

Comment: How are you executing Maven on the console ? Do you simply run 'mvn clean compile' or something else ?

Comment: @MichalKalinowski What happened when you excluded `**/*.java`?

Comment: My first question about that is: Why do you like to compile only a limited number of your classes in your project? It sounds you have to create multiple modules instead of one?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I migrate really huge Ant project (about 800 modules) into Maven. This project is build once a week, so I have to stick with its structure until I finish my work there so I can always build it with Ant. That's why I need to do this hackin' crap I'm asking about.

Comment: Could you please post the whole pom?

Comment: Can you explain: you use 'maven-compiler-plugin' with 'includes', but all classes are compiled?

Comment: As I already wrote, all 14 classes are compiled then.

Comment: i want help you, but I cann't reproduce the problem. Only inluded classes are compiled in my code

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simple app with 3 classes.

```
com/company/Obj1.java
com/company/Obj2.java
com/company/inner/Obj3.java
```

`build` in `pom.xml`

```
<build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0.2</version>
               <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                  <includes>
                     <include>com/company/inner/*.java</include>
                  </includes>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>

   </build>
```

result: 1 class is compiled.
And any combination of includes is working well
or you mean something else?

Comment: OMG! Works! But with version 2.0.2 of the compiler! Versions 2.5.1 and 2.3.2 ignore includes and excludes. It seems we found a bug here.

Comment: Interesting... What I wrote above is true in my case (my module), but in general, with just so simple project like the @Ilya's example, there's no problem even with new version of `maven-compiler-plugin`. It seems there is something in my module's `pom.xml` or in parents' hierarchy (there is a few). I'll try to investigate my case and find the answer what's actually wrong. If it's really some problem with Maven compiler, I'll create JIRA ticket for them.

Comment: You can run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see what is the final configuration used when building your project.

Comment: OK. Here is the result of my investigation. Version up to 2.1 of `maven-compiler-plugin` works as expected - it compiles just what you want by `<includes>` and `<excludes>` tags of its configuration. Version 2.2 and up have some bug (that's how I see it) that compiles what you want but also classes within source directories that are needed to successful compilation.

Comment: I accept this @Ilya answer and give my bounty since it's the answer that shows that compiler version matters here.

Comment: Does it work if Obj3 has reference of Obj1 or 2?

Answer (score 8):

I have faced a similar situation. We needed to hot swap only modified files to our remote docker container in order to improve changes-deploy time. This is how we solved it.

Add includes option in build plugin with command line argument.
Note since we wanted to add multiple files, so we have used **includes** and not **include**

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <includes>${changed.classes}</includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now run compile phase with argument, example:

```
mvn compile -Dchanged.classes=com/demo/ClassA.java,com/demo/ClassB.java,com/demo2/*
```

Answer (score 2):

maven-compiler-plugin using Ant-like inclusion/exclusion notation.
You can see examples in Ant documentation [Ant FileSet Type](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html#symlink)

If you are want include only files from one directory, you need write it like you did:

```
<include>com/example/dao/bean/*.java</include>
```

To include also subdirectories from path, it will be:

```
<include>com/example/dao/bean/**/*.java</include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no difficulty including or excluding files for compilation with maven compiler plugin `2.5.1`.  [Here](https://github.com/maruhgar/mvn-examples/tree/master/selective-compile) is the dummy project I used for the purpose.  Perhaps the `include` pattern that you use is different.