# Better understanding of maven compile exclusions

Tags: java, maven, javac

I am attempting to move a long list of projects to maven as part of a proof of concept project.  The first step is getting them to compile, so that I can show the development teams that this can be done so I can work with them to fully mavenize the projects.

A number of these projects are failing on a single bad java class.  I've tried doing exclusions on these files, and I can see that the exclusion is seen by maven (the line

```
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to...
```

changes the number of source files after I add the exclusion), BUT the same source file will still cause the same error during the compilation process.

It appears that these files are often, thought not always, generated files.  But in any case, it is attempting to compile the files that I've asked it not to compile.  So my questions are:
1)  Are these files being added back in by the compiler as it builds it's compile-time dependencies?  If so, is there a a way trace back which files call which files that doesn't involve reading all the (sometimes hundreds of) sources?
2)  Is there a better way to get exclusions via maven?

Thanks!

Comment: what maven goal did you run ?

Comment: you can check `mvn dependency:tree` to see detailed dependencies which are being added with what scope, that would help

Comment: dependency tree is only showing me the libraries that are being added, it doesn't appear to tell me anything about the actual .java files that are being compiled...?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a reported, unresolved bug, [MCOMPILER-174](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-174):

> it doesn't pass the file in with the list of .java files to javac. However, it still passes in the ./src/ directory under the -sourcepath option to the javac command. Thus, javac still knows that the file exists and can try to compile it anyways under certain circumstances.

(Also discussed in [Compiling only selected files in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051620/compiling-only-selected-files-in-maven).)

You could create a Maven build that would use an alternative `src` directory and populate it at the start of the build but, if you're trying to identify the failure caused by removing this file, I suggest either excluding it through your IDE or moving it on the file system.