# Slow compilation with jOOQ 3.6+, plain SQL, and the javac compiler

Tags: java, compilation, java-8, jooq

The following bug was reported to the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/grv6Wu_sFtA). It really seems to be a bug in the javac compiler related to rather "complex" type inference work done by the compiler in the context of using an internal DSL like [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) is.

Given the general nature of the bug, I'm documenting it here on Stack Overflow for others to help apply workarounds if they run into it. On a high level, it seems to be a compiler performance regression due to [JEP 101: Generalized Target-Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101), which was introduced in Java 8 and has caused 1-2 issues in the past.

The following relatively harmless class takes around 20 seconds to compile with jdk 1.8.0_60 or 1.8.0_66 on Windows using Maven and jOOQ 3.7:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.field;

import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;

public class Test {
    public void method() {
        DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
           .select()
           .where(DSL.trueCondition())
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
           .and(field("client.id").eq(field("client_id")))
        ;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<project 
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>compilation-issues</groupId>
    <artifactId>compilation-issues</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### Configurations when this issue doesn't appear:

- Using jOOQ 3.5 (anything prior to 3.6.0)
- Using jOOQ with generated classes rather than the above "plain SQL" API
- Using Java 7
- Using the Eclipse compiler

Comment: Been there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707387/troubleshoot-slow-compilation - good to see your workarounds. I came to similar conclusions: avoid static imports and use lots of intermediate variables to help type inference... And this is the bug, I think: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051946

Comment: @assylias: Huh, I knew I had seen something similar before! Thanks for linking - this is a duplicate, then. I've filed another bug to Oracle for this, too. Let's see if this adds a bit more weight :-/

Comment: @LukasEder, thanks for the bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145742, as you can see it has been closed by a member of our team. The reason is because these performance issues have been fixed in JDK 9. So if you guys use the most current version of it you won't see the reported issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VicenteRomero. I had seen the duplicate of my report some time after I reported my version. Is there any chance this will be backported to JDK 8? It seems lie a rather significant issue for people using overloading and generics rather heavily...

Comment: Hi @LukasEder, sorry for the very late response, I have been out for a long while. Well so far it hasn't been backported and I don't think that it will be. I think one way to call the attention on this bug is to send an email to: jdk8u-dev@openjdk.java.net these are they guys maintaining JDK 8 and probably they will be interested in backporting the bug

Comment: @VicenteRomero: Thanks for getting back to me! I've found a workaround by backwards incompatibly removing some API introduced recently at the time (that no one was using yet). That fixed the issue for jOOQ. I didn't check if the compiler still has the problem. Currently, compared to the Eclipse compiler, javac performs just fine on jOOQ code.

Comment: Sure @LukasEder please let me know of any case you find for which javac is noticeably slower than eclipse. Please report them at: compiler-dev at openjdk.java.net

Comment: @LukasEder are you already using JDK 9?

Comment: @VicenteRomero: Yes for occasional tests, but still need to set up the CI...

Comment: @LukasEder, I see, please message me if you find any other javac issue. I will try to check in from time to time

Comment: @VicenteRomero: Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Explanation

In jOOQ 3.6 (when this problem first appears), the `DSL.field()` API saw 22 new overloads taking different `Row` types as arguments:

- [`DSL.field(Row1<T1>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Row1-)
- [`DSL.field(Row2<T1, T2>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Row2-)
- [`DSL.field(Row3<T1, T2, T3>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Row3-)
- ...

It appears that with this particular API usage above, the new overloads cause a lot of trouble when the javac compiler tries to find the most specific overload among all the possible overloads. The following workaround compiles instantly:

## Fix

A fix is under way for releases [3.9.0](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5233), [3.8.1](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5235), [3.7.4](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5234), [3.6.5](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5236), removing these methods again from the public API, and providing a renamed substitute that does not cause any overloading issues.

## Workarounds

#### 1. Helping the compiler select the most specific `DSL.field()` overload

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.field;

import org.jooq.Field;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;

public class Test {
    public void method() {
        Field<Object> f1 = field("client.id");
        Field<Object> f2 = field("client_id");
        DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
           .select()
           .where(DSL.trueCondition())
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
           .and(f1.eq(f2))
        ;
    }
}
```

#### 2. Preventing target type inference in the context of the `and()` method entirely

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.field;

import org.jooq.Condition;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;

public class Test {
    public void method() {
        Condition condition = field("client.id").eq(field("client_id"));
        DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
           .select()
           .where(DSL.trueCondition())
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
           .and(condition)
        ;
    }
}
```

## More info

This has actually been reported on Stack Overflow before:

- [Troubleshoot slow compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707387/troubleshoot-slow-compilation)
- http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8086048

And it has been discussed also on the jOOQ user group:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/vuaG9d9krDk
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/grv6Wu_sFtA