# Java 8 - Increase in compilation time on increasing for loops in code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This is very weird thing that we are observing in Java 8. When we are continuously increasing inner for loops in a java program, code compilation time increases exponentially.

Inner for loops are applied in code because of a elastic search query that has 8 aggregation factor.

For example : When number of inner for loops is 6, code compilation time is 2 mins, when increased to 7 loops compilation time increases to 3 min. However when number of inner loop increase to 8, compilation time increases to 11 mins.

```
for (int pac = 0; pac < primaryAggs.length(); pac++) {
                JSONObject primaryAgg = primaryAggs.getJSONObject(pac);
                JSONArray f1Aggs = primaryAgg.getJSONObject("field1").getJSONArray("buckets");
                for (int dac = 0; dac < f1Aggs.length(); dac++) {
                    JSONObject f1Agg = f1Aggs.getJSONObject(dac);
                    JSONArray f2Aggs = f1Agg.getJSONObject("field2").getJSONArray("buckets");
                    for (int dealac = 0; dealac < f2Aggs.length(); dealac++) {
                        JSONObject f2Agg = f2Aggs.getJSONObject(dealac);
                        JSONArray f2Aggs = f2Agg.getJSONObject("field3").getJSONArray("buckets");
                        for (int sac = 0; sac < f2Aggs.length(); sac++) {
                            JSONObject f2Agg = f2Aggs.getJSONObject(sac);
                            JSONArray f3Aggs = f2Agg.getJSONObject("field4")
                                    .getJSONArray("buckets");
                            for (int bac = 0; bac < f3Aggs.length(); bac++) {
                                JSONObject f3Agg = f3Aggs.getJSONObject(bac);
                                JSONArray f4Aggs = f3Agg.getJSONObject("field5")
                                        .getJSONArray("buckets");
                                for (int j = 0; j < f4Aggs.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject f4Agg = f4Aggs.getJSONObject(j);
                                    JSONArray f5Aggs = f4Agg.getJSONObject("field6")
                                            .getJSONArray("buckets");
                                    for (int k = 0; k < f5Aggs.length(); k++) {
                                        JSONObject f5Agg = f5Aggs.getJSONObject(k);
                                        JSONArray f6Aggs = f5Agg.getJSONObject("field7")
                                                .getJSONArray("buckets");
                                        for (int l = 0; l < f6Aggs.length(); l++) {
                                            JSONObject f6Agg = f6Aggs.getJSONObject(l);


                                            // do processing of ES result set
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            bulkProcessor.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30707387/829571

Comment: Already went through it but no success.

Comment: Interesting observation; but just for the record: you should try to avoid writing such code in the first place --- its called [SLA](https://dzone.com/articles/the-single-level-of-abstraction-principle)