# mvn install only with modified files in hg repository

Tags: java, maven, mercurial, maven-3

I've a java project (in mercurial repository). I'm compiling and generating jar using maven. I've attached my pom.xml image below.
[image]

Every time compiling all available file (>1500 java files) taking much time. Is there any why that I can specify files that need to be compiled and update those latest class files in existing jars?

I would like to include files that are part of hg pull (added/modified) and compile only those specific files instead of all files.

Comment: One risk of incremental builds that depend on file timestamps is that the timestamps aren't always going to be updated the way you expect from a source control tool. A file newer to you from another branch might have an older timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but not recommended:

- https://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Java-Maven-Compile-Only-Changed-Files
- [Maven compiler recompile all files instead modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963012/maven-compiler-recompile-all-files-instead-modified/19653164#19653164)

Btw. I have no idea what you mean by "taking much time", but I have in my project several thousand classes and compilation takes several seconds (if I disable tests), so maybe the the issue that your build is taking too long is somewhere else then compilation of Java classes.