# Maven still compiling project despite already being compiled

Tags: maven, testing

I have a Maven project which I'm trying to use in some GHAs. I'm attempting to parallelize tests and before-hand I build the project thus allowing the tests to simply run without compiling as-well, at-least in theory.

The steps I follow are:

1. run `mvn -B test-compile`
2. run `mvn -B -Dtest=${random-test-name} test`

The problem despite containing the compiled `target` folder, the maven project still re-compiles when running the test. Is there a way to avoid this occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run the goal `surefire:test`, instead of the phase `test`, that should only execute tests:

```
mvn -B -Dtest=${random-test-name} surefire:test
```

The output looks like:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.example:guide-spring-boot >--------------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-complete 0.1.0
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0:test (default-cli) @ guide-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.springboot.HelloControllerTest
true
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.111 s - in com.example.springboot.HelloControllerTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.450 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-09T10:56:21+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your build setup, incremental compilation may also help you. That way, Maven will only compile source files that have changed (and other source files that depend on those changes) while skipping compiled code that is up-to-date. This, however, requires that your compiler actually supports this.

For Java:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Note:** An explanation as to why the flag needs to be `false` is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653164/5736633

For Kotlin:

```xml
<properties>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
</properties>
```

By doing this with your current setup, Maven (or better to say the compiler) would recognize that everything is compiled and skip compilation. However, if there's anything missing, the compiler will recompile those parts rather than giving you an error.

This may also help you during development if your project is larger, as it will accelerate any subsequent compilations. It is, however, not entirely fool-proof, so, in case you do encounter weird compiler errors or `NoSuchMethod` exceptions at runtime, simply run a `mvn clean` to enforce a full recompilation.

**Edit:** After reading the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation) for this, I realized that this is much more confusing than I thought. Setting `useIncrementalCompilation` to `true` will recompile the whole module if any source file has changed. Setting it to `false` will only recompile source files that have changed, but it will **not** check for any dependencies that would require recompilation as well. As I am coming from the Kotlin world where incremental compilation works really well, I assumed that the Java compiler would be equally smart, but apparently, it is not.